# Single word request: "universally fatal" (especially to humans) without any connotation of intentionality or evil?

Tags: single-word-requests

Malign seems great, but it carries connotations of deliberate evil (like "malevolent").

Fatal or terminal might work, but aren't specific enough.

Comment: Why one word? Please supply sentence with blank,

Comment: What do you mean by ‘universally’ fatal? Do you mean that it will always cause death (e.g., lack of oxygen), or that it will cause death on a universal scale (e.g., giant meteor hitting the earth, wiping out life as we know it)?

Comment: Context would also indicate whether a word referencing a specific kind of death would fit, such as "toxic" (which refers to poisoning), or "terminal" (which refers to illness).

Answer (score 3):

In my experience the word Lethal may be a good choice here.

Answer (score 0):

Three words starting with *C* in a roughly ascending order of magnitude.

[calamitous](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/calamitous) - *a serious accident or bad event causing damage or suffering*

[catastrophic](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/catastrophic) - *a sudden event that causes very great trouble or destruction*

[cataclysmic](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cataclysm) - *an event that causes a lot of destruction, or a sudden, violent change*

<sub>Definitions courtesy of [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org)</sub>